# How to display html after all angularjs processing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working with angularjs and I have a table with rows and columns dynamically created with ng-repeat. Each cell has a directive that has ng-include. While the contents of the cell are processed, ng-repeat is terminated and the table is displayed with empty cells for a moment. I would like to block the page view until all angular processing has been finalized. It is possible?

I load the rows and columns to load a table, ex:

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
         <my-directive row="row" col="col" tamplate-cell-url="{{templateCellUrl}}">
         </my-directive>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

my directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      row: '=',
      col: '=',
      templateCellUrl: '@'
    },
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.url = function () {
        return scope.templateCellUrl || 'cell-default.html'
      }
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="url()"></div>'
  }
})
```

Comment: too brief, but sounds like `ng-cloak` (css) or `resolve` (angular.config)

Comment: how many $scope variables are you loading?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure, I edited my question and includes details of the code...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is one simple solution for this. Use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` for this

```
<div ng-hide="variable == undefined">
//Your HTML Code
</div>
```

In this above code example it will hide your html content if the $scope.variable is undefined(means it is not yet initialized). If something gets assigned to it, it will show you the DOM content.

For multiple variables use and condition.

Comment: Rakesh, I thought about it but I could not know when all ng-include ends to assign a value to that variable

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `ng-cloak` directive.

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

See it here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

So in your cell directive you could do:

```
<div ng-cloak>
      <ng-include src="something.html'"></ng-include>           
</div>
```

Comment: Even thought the url is answer to the question it is always a good practice to add some description to the url.

Comment: Ng-cloak resolves if I do not want to display the empty "{{}}" angularjs keys before assigning the values. In my case it does not work because it is different. The point is that ng-repeat terminates before full loading of the directives and ng-include of each cell. Tks!

Comment: So in the inner (cell) directive just do: `<div ng-cloak>
            <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/grid-content-base.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>`